Authentication/ security Context object is getting lost after upgrade from Spring frame 5 to 6
We recently upgraded our project from Spring framework 5 to 6 and after the upgrade, we have lost the authentication object. we came across this article which says
In Spring Security 6, the default behavior is that the SecurityContextHolderFilter will only read the SecurityContext from SecurityContextRepository and populate it in the SecurityContextHolder. Users now must explicitly save the SecurityContext with the SecurityContextRepository if they want the SecurityContext to persist between requests.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/session-management.html#_require_explicit_saving_of_securitycontextrepository
We have added the required configuration in securityConfig
@Bean
        public SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
            return new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
                new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
                new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()
            );
        }

and then we are saving the context on authentication success
 org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext context= SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        context.setAuthentication(authentication);
        DelegatingSecurityContextRepository secRepo=new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository();
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
        
        secRepo.saveContext(context, request, response); 

But we cant seem to save the context in security Repository permanently.
Any ideas/ solutions are welcomed
We tried to save the security context in scurityRepo but that didnt worked.
Not sure but does it looks like issue with cookies ?
